# Payment Notifications to users

Tags: node.js, reactjs, notifications, webhooks, flutterwave

I'm building an application in which we have worked on Payment gateway named flutterwave.
And now the scenario is on every success or failure of a payment, I receive a webhook and then we take further actions such as sending emails, SMS and updating the statuses of the payment in the DB.

For now, we have implemented polling in the client side and for a particular time span if the client receives a status (success or fail) we show it otherwise they can check later it in the payment history page.

Now we want to remove this polling and update users in real time about the success or failure of a payment.
What are the ways by which we can achieve this?

The questions are how we will notify a specific user about the same as we have a multiplatform app and the same user can be logged in different platforms.

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is a real-time communication pattern with [WebSockets](https://www.wallarm.com/what/a-simple-explanation-of-what-a-websocket-is) a layer 7 protocol in the [OSI model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OSI_model) which offers bi-directional communication.

This means that you can establish communication between your servers and your user's browser (client). As a result, you can send notification data to the client and consume and react to the notification, by showing visual cues in your UI for the user to see.

Some examples of implementing WebSockets with Socket.io and Nodejs: https://dev.to/novu/sending-real-time-notifications-with-socketio-in-nodejs-1l5j

There are also paid services that can offer this functionality like Pusher, and I would actually recommend that route at the beginning so you can avoid spending too much time implementing this and focus more on the stuff that matters and is part of your roadmap.

Additionally, you can use [Push Notifications](https://vwo.com/push-notifications/) as another way to notify your users even when they are not using the app.